# How to get rid of "ERROR: APK path is not specified for module" in android studio?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to run my flutter app on my android phone, but it almost automatically says I need to add an apk path when i press the run button.

I've read multiple answers yet none of them work for me. I tried deleting .iml and tried adding an apk path but i don't have an apk path to add. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Output Directory is not set to a valid directory. Note that relative paths are not supported, at least in IntelliJ 14.

Project Structure (Cmd-;) > Modules > Paths:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOsBV.png)

Set Compiler output to "Use module compile output path", then choose/create the desired output directory for the APK.